# List and Map null check

Tags: java

What is fundamental difference between style of null and empty check of a List or a Map.

```
nameList!=null && !nameList.isEmpty()
```

or

```
CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(nameList)
```

and for Map

```
nameMap!=null && !nameMap.isEmpty()
```

or

```
MapUtils.isNotEmpty(nameMap)
```

Can these two approaches be used interchangeably?
Which should be better considering Java enterprise coding standards too?

Comment: see the code of CollectionUtils, for example, the ColletionUtils from Hadoop (http://goo.gl/GbBm98) is `collection == null || collection.isEmpty()` the same as yours!.

Comment: @AVolpe I am refering to apache.commons.collections framework class. Will learn Hadoop when get a chance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about Apache Commons library, this:

```
nameMap!=null && !nameMap.isEmpty()
```

is equivalent to:

```
MapUtils.isNotEmpty(nameMap)
```

And yes, you can use them interchangebly.